# Work with TFS programmatically from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tfs

I need to call TFS client from ASP.NET Web App.

In IIS I create an application pool dedicated to my web app:

- Identity: LocalSystem
- Managed pipeline mode: Classic
- Enable 32bit application: True
- Load user profile: True

I have configured authentication in IIS for my Web App:

- Anonymous Authentication: False
- APS.NET impersonation: True
- Forms Authentication: False
- Windows Authentication:True

I have configured web.config for my web app:

- authorization
- deny users=?
- authentication mode=Windows
- identity impersonate=true

The server is a Windows Server 2012 (running in a VM) with TFS 2013. The VM is in a domain. User are all Domain Users. All user are configured in TFS Team.

In my web app code behind, I call TFS in that way

```
var credential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsHelper.TfsDefaultCollectionUri, credential);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Problem:

If the Domain user is not Local Administrator of the VM, the "login" to TFS via EnsureAuthenticated is VERY VERY SLOW.

If I give to Domain user, Local Administrator Role, the "login" is fast (IMMEDIATE).

Comment: Yes, Windows Server 2012 as VM. Thanks.

Comment: If you run your C# code from a console application you get the same slowness?

Comment: Yes the same. The problem appears to be related to the fact that users do not have access (login) to the VM.
If I give a user access and the user login into the VM, the account becomes fast, although I remove access.